# JS thread in react native is having low fps

Tags: performance, react-native, profiling, android-profiler

I am having significant JS thread frame drop(low fps), when I am running my react native app on  android devices. It affects the responsiveness of the screen on devices with less RAM. Any suggestions(any tool or profiler) on how can I detect frame drops i.e. which component is causing frame drop?

Answer (score 2):

https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling is a good starting point.

The article references `systrace`, which is now integrated into the Android Studio CPU profiler. Just [record](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#method_traces) a trace using the Trace System Calls configuration. The UI is similar to the legacy `systrace` tool but focuses on your app's process so it should make it easier to find the JS Thread. For how to use System Trace in Android Studio, please check out this video: https://youtu.be/EjmIit_amnE.